# How can i get SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in prestashop tpl page

Tags: frameworks, themes, smarty, prestashop, document-root

Can any one help me?
I need document_root variable value in tpl page.
I am using presta shop as framework. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: please explain your purpose, and i may be able to help you and give you a way to use native prestashop code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to assign a smarty variable in a Prestashop hook for that

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('document_root', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

Use it like this in your tpl file.

```
{$document_root}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the absolute path to the shop with `{$smarty.const._PS_ROOT_DIR_}`